# Connecting Higher Highs and Lower Lows with a line

Tags: pine-script

I've made a simple script that shows the difference between the ticker price and de 200ema price.
Now I want to connect al the higher highs and lower lows with each other but I fail to do so.

### this is my the current code:

myEMA = ema(close, 200)
currentPrice = close

price = currentPrice - myEMA

plot(price)

Is there anybody that can help me?

[here's a picture of how it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9zoS.png)

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve is called an expanding window maximum/minimum. In pinescript both can be computed efficiently as follows:

```
max = 0.,min = 0.
max := nz(max(price,max[1]),price)
min := nz(min(price,min[1]),price)
```